# Is it better for performance issues to run Microsoft Teams on macOS or in a virtual machine with windows?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ms-office, virtualization, office-365

Microsoft Teams is known to cause performance issues on Mac OS.

I have a MacBook Pro 13' 2020 with 16 GB Ram and I was wondering if it would be better for overall performance to run Teams on a Virtual Machine running Windows instead.

Some discussions:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/performance-issue-on-mac-when-sharing-screen-in/9b96f652-d2d2-40f4-aaf8-a921273fd165
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/why-teams-is-slowing-down-my-mac/m-p/1334064
- https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40410775-please-fix-desktop-app-performance-on-macos-cons